# Using UITabbaritem as a UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is there a way to use UITabbaritem as a UIButton?
I am trying to make a Tabbar that its items don't change the view. Just want them to do simple actions in the same view controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably possible, by creating a `UITabBarDelegate` and implementing the correct methods, but doing so would violate Apple's [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/SpecialViews/SpecialViews.html) and cause your app to be rejected. `UIToolbar` is the correct class to use for what you're describing. From that doc:

> A tab bar gives users the ability to
>   switch among different modes or views
>   in an application, and users should be
>   able to access these modes from
>   everywhere in the application.
>   However, a tab bar should never be
>   used as a toolbar, which contains
>   buttons that act on elements in the
>   current mode (see “Toolbars” for more
>   information on toolbars).

Answer (score 1):

No. It inherits from UIBarItems:NSObject. UIButton inherits from UIControl.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   UIButton *chatButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [chatButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [chatButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        chatButton.frame = (CGRect) {
            .size.width = 30,
            .size.height = 35,
        };
        UIBarButtonItem *barBackButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:chatButton];
        [navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barBackButton];

    NSArray *barItemArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:navigationItem,nil];
    [navigationBar setItems:barItemArray];
```